# How can I iterate over each data label of each series

Tags: python-pptx

I have a chart where I want to display only some datalabels on the charts. I iterated on `series.points` but I am not able to get the present datalabel value.

Even when I use `number_format="0.0%"`, all the datalabels value becomes multiplied by 100.

```
            for point in series.points:
                print(dir(point.data_label))
```

The output should exact datalabel of that point instead of multiplied by 100 value and point datalabel value less than 2 should be hidden.

[image: Chart Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data-label values are not available directly as they are not actually written to the PPTX file. Luckily, they are easy to calculate for yourself.

If you want to change the data labels selectively, you'll need to replace ones you don't want to show with a blank string ("").

Chart values are available on `chart.series[i].values`:

```
for series in chart.series:
    print(series.values)
```

A series is a set of bars all the same color, so you might need to rearrange these values for your particular use.

The percentage format type is meant to be applied to proportion values, like turn 0.5 into 50%. So if you want to use that format, you need to make sure your chart values are in that form. If you just want to append a "%" character, use "0.0\%" (note the backslash).